# Can I add the same Facebook pixel for 2 websites?

Tags: facebook, google-tag-manager

The Facebook account that I use is a collective account for 2 services, which have 2 different websites, but they are the same company. I want to add the same pixel to the second (new) website. I use Google Tag Manager.

Comment: No, you need to add the other website to Facebook Pixel and it'll give you the new code, you then add that to Google Tag Manager.

Comment: But I want to post from the same account and use the audience, so I don't want to add a brand new one.